# Point feature class from excel Spreadsheet lat long

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.3, excel

I imported an excel spreadsheet of a couple hundred lat long coordinates that I wanted to become points. The majority of them were projected correctly except for a few were in the wrong hemisphere. I went in and manually added a (-) in front of the longitude to bring the points to the western hemisphere (it seems that the (-) was lost in translation or my file had errors).

The problem is that the attribute table now has the correct coordinates but the points are still in the eastern hemisphere.

I manually changed the coordinates in the attribute table during an editing session but the new coordinates have not been displayed on the map. Is there a way of changing the points coordinates in ArcMap without uploading an new edited excel sheet?

[image]

Comment: Can you include the row of one such record which is in the wrong hemisphere, and the precise steps, starting with opening ArcMap with a Blank Map, that you performed to see this, please?  I suspect that documenting the exact steps will enable you to discover where you went astray, and if not, then we should then be in a good position to help you.

Comment: Did you manually change them in the spreadsheet then re-upload them? If you just changed them in the attribute table it might not reflect in the layer.

Comment: @Kingfisher, that is exactly what I did... sadly I did not realize the error until i had manuall attached a rasterized image to each point using a database... at this point i am trying everything to keep from having to re-upload them.

Comment: @PolyGeo I'm working on uploading a snapshot of the record although it doesn't show much. What I did after realizing the error was enter an editing session, open the tttribute table and manually edit it to the correct lat long coordinates.

Comment: I think you should look into the Field Calculator that lets you get at the geometry properties for a feature using SHAPE tokens.  Find out which ones access the x and y coordinates and then calculate them equal to your Longitude and Latitude_N fields respectively.  Test on a copy of your data first.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @PolyGeo I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is.  Start editing the layer, double click on the point, or edit vertices, then right click on the point and select 'Move To'.  You will be presented with a dialog asking for the coordinates to move to.  Then simply add the - to whichever coordinate and hit enter.  The point will move to the correct coordinates.
[image]

[image]

As Polygeo stated in his comment, if you've already corrected the lat long attributes, you can use the field calculator on the SHAPE field to alter the geometry.
Here is a code sample for update X and Y (or Lat Long) - Python Parser

```
   def XYsetVALUE( shape, X_value, Y_value):
       point = shape.getPart(0)
       point.X = X_value
       point.Y = Y_value
       return point
```

Then call the function: XYsetVALUE( !SHAPE!, !Your X field!, !Your Y field!)

Note that you must be editing to alter the geometry.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh. Thank you very much, I knew there had to be a simple way to do it.

Comment: One liner in field calculator: arcpy.Point(!xf!,!yf)